# Webpack SASS loader cannot dedupe common SCSS imports

Tags: sass, webpack, webpack-dev-server, node-sass

I have the following structure:

```
node_modules
  - my_component
    - font
    - scss
      - my_component.scss
src
  - my_app.js
  - my_app.scss
```

I'm trying to import the styles in `my_component.scss`. This file contains `@font-face` declarations with references to `../font/`. So something like:

```
// my_component.scss
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue';
  font-weight: $weight-medium;
  src: url('../font/font-file.eot');
}
```

In `my_app.js` I'm requiring the SCSS file associated with it. So

```
// my_app.js

require('./my_app.scss');

//other app-specific code
```

I'm `my_app.scss`, I'm importing `my_component.scss`:

```
// my_app.scss

import 'my_component';
```

and the `sassConfig` is set to resolve to `node_modules/my_component/scss` so that the import works.

My loader config uses `sass-loader`, `resolve-url-loader` and `css-loader`. Here's a snippet:

```
//loaders.js

loaders.push({
  test: /\.scss$/,
  loader: 'style!css?sourcemap!resolve-url!sass?sourceMap'
});
```

Here is what I observe:

1. When I run `webpack-dev-server`, the `url` references resolve correctly
2. However, when I run `webpack` with the same conf file, I get `Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ../font/font-file.ttf` in `src/font/`

Things I've tried:

1. Using a `$font-path` variable to refer to `../fonts` and setting it to `node_modules/my_components/font`
2. Checking the order of my loaders, updating my webpack version etc.

**Update**

My `sassLoader` config previously had configuration for [node-sass-import-once](https://github.com/at-import/node-sass-import-once). When I removed it, my font urls started resolving again, however my generated CSS contains a ton of duplicate styles.

node-sass is repeatedly importing each `@import` without doing any sort of deduping (I know it's not supposed to be able to do it by itself). But `node-sass-import-once` which is meant for this sort of thing, breaks resolve-url-loader.

Here are my questions:

1. Why does node-sass-import-once break the Webpack resolve-url-loader?
2. Is there any way to dedupe the imports Webpack and get generated CSS free of style duplication?

Answer (score 3):

Without seeing your Webpack config I can only hazard a guess but it looks like you are trying to import a CSS file from `node_modules`.

When you want to import CSS from `node_modules` you may have to use the `~`. As sokra himself says in [this issue](https://github.com/webpack/css-loader/issues/12):

> css @import is relative to the current directory. For resolving "like a module" you can prefix ~.

So maybe something like `` @import `~module/my_component.scss`; `` might do the trick.

Resolving imports this way also solved an issue I had where `x.css` was required by `x.js` and imported by `y.css` when `x.css` imported some sass variable config. Using [resolve.alias](https://webpack.github.io/docs/resolving.html#aliasing) in Webpack config I could simply do something like:

```
// webpack.config.js
resolve: {
  alias: {
    styles: 'src/styles/'
  }
}
```

And then use the tilde to import:

```
// y.css
@import `~styles/x.scss
```

If this works then you needn't remove the`node-sass-import-once` and everything should resolve correctly.

Comment: I'll give it a try but tilde imports have pretty much never worked for me. Will update with my webpack config. Yes I am trying to import from `node_modules`

Comment: Looks like I only have a few minutes left to award the bounty. I'll award it to you in appreciation of you taking a look at the question and attempting to answer, but I'll leave it open for other folks to answer later on.